# facing an issue while includeing a file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have include a file sidebar.php in view of index page but it gives me a error like these

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: include(sidebar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 38

and other error is these

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: include(): Failed opening 'sidebar.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 38

the file sidebar.php is in the same directory and the code is as follows:

```
  <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">


            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>
            <!-- /sidebar menu -->
          </div>
        </div>
```

i am novice here so please forgive!

Comment: Give full directory path of  `sidebar.php`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam now how do i that ?

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of using raw php function (assuming your `sidebar.php` is in same directory where you will use this)

```
$this->load->view('sidebar');
```

Comment: these one is not working any other suggestions please!

Comment: show your `views` directory structure first with files

Comment: answer revised, try now

Comment: Can you tell me the version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: It is 3.0 version of CI

Comment: where did you put your sidebar.php file.? put it in `views` folder. Then try this answer

Answer (score 0):

They way you including file `sidebar.php` should be root folder where main `index.php` located.

Or you should use full file path `C:\xampp\htdocs\.....YOUR PROJECT FILE DIRECToRY\sidebar.php`

Or You can Use `FCPATH` `APPPATH` to get the filepath

**Example**

if your sidebar.php is in root folder `<?php include FCPATH.'sidebar.php'; ?>`

if it is inside application folder use `<?php include APPPATH.'sidebar.php'; ?>`

Comment: those must work.where is your sidebar.php file located?

Comment: it is located in the same view directory where index.php page is located ! the reason i think it is happening because one of my team member actually made some changes in loader.php file and now i am facing such issues bcz he forgot where he made changes!!

Comment: no. include is php basic function.it does include.check the spelling and case sensitive.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting g checklist for this kind of mistakes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: some thing I said in the answer.I think u did not understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Load your sidebar in your controller

```
public function sources()
{
$this->load->view("pages/header/head", $data);
$this->load->view("pages/sidebar"
$this->load->view("admin/main");
$this->load->view("pages/footer/footer");
}
```

Of course adapted to your code